# Iterate through properties of an object

Tags: javascript, performance

I need to round numeric values for properties of a given object.
The following code works fine, but I am concerned if there is a way to make it faster.

I am targeting latest Chrome and Firefox.

http://jsbin.com/bahedegoni/edit?html,output

```
window.app = {
            start: function () {
                var cmd = {
                    a: 11.12,
                    b: 0.29,
                    c: 'x',
                    d: 'y'
                };
                Object.keys(cmd).forEach(function (prop) {
                    if (typeof cmd[prop] === 'number') {
                        cmd[prop] = Math.round(cmd[prop]);
                    }

                }.bind(this));
                console.log(cmd);
            }
        };
```

Comment: This seems like a really strange thing to do. What's the context?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my specific case, cmd properties will be populated with different values including from a IDOMClientRect result.I need to round those value as only integer.

Comment: What is `cmd`, though?

Comment: In my real app, cmd is an object which contains values for position related DOM modification. Like cmd.top = 10 which will be translate to a CSS style top position on a DOM element of 10. There is no sense in setting CSS properties to not integer values when the unit is pixel, so  this is the reasons for code :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to use `bind`; you don't rely on `this` anywhere in the code, so it doesn't matter what the `this`-context is.

Secondly, the "original" way to iterate objects in JavaScript is to use a `for...in` loop. However, it will also iterate inherited properties, so it's good practice to check if the key's the object's own key by using `hasOwnProperty`. The basic construction looks like so:

```
var key;
for(key in object) {
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue; // skip inherited properties
  // ... do something
}
```

Thirdly, due to the way JavaScript expresses a `NaN` (Not A Number) value, it turns out that `typeof NaN === 'number'`. Of course, it doesn't really matter here since `Math.round(NaN)` is still `NaN`.

Point is, this would probably be one of the simplest implementations:

```
var key;
for(key in cmd) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof cmd[key] === 'number') {
    cmd[key] = Math.round(cmd[key]);
  }
}
```